# Click button using command-prompt

Tags: button, cmd, click, installation, command-prompt

I need to install a program using cmd(hoping to create an batch file lately).

I have executed the program using cmd. After Installation window pops up how do I click those buttons using command prompt?

Can I use sequence of tab key, arrow keys and enter key using cmd to install the program?

Comment: check if the program has a silent install mode.

Comment: we'd probably need to know which program..

Answer (score 0):

You can check out AutoHotKeys

http://ahkscript.org/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options. Some installers have command line arguments support for silent installation. Some can be extracted using specific softwares. if so there will be a file to describe it inside extracted content. Some supports hot keys. In most cases it is possible without clicking ui buttons